# Getting HTML to linebreak in django admin's display

Tags: python, html, django, format

I have this as my django display

[image]

The code for doing this is:

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    product = models.ManyToManyField('Product', null =True)

    def get_products(self):
        return "\n".join([p.products for p in self.product.all()])

class Product(models.Model):
    products = models.CharField(max_length=256, null =True)

    def __unicode__(self):
         return self.products
```

views.py:

```
class PurchaseOrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   fields = ['product']
   list_display = ('get_products')
```

So I've attempted to do this:

```
from django.utils.html import format_html

 def get_products(self):
    return format_html(" <p> </p>").join([p.products for p in self.product.all()])
```

however, it's still not returning it in HTML. Or rather, the way I want it in the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the field to allow tags for the HTML to show up in the admin list display:

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    product = models.ManyToManyField('Product', null =True)

    def get_products(self):
        return "<br />".join([p.products for p in self.product.all()])
    get_products.allow_tags = True
```

See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/) for more information.

Comment: Is there an allow tag while you're in models? I actually can't get this to compile while in admin. Any idea how to get it for models?

Comment: My sample is on your model class.